# Repeating "to" in conjunction

Tags: grammaticality

May I know which sentence is grammatical?

I am not sure whether we need to repeat the "to".

> The method helps to improve the quality of the software, shorten the time to market, and lower production costs.
>
> The method helps to improve the quality of the software, **to** shorten the time to market, and **to** lower production costs.

Comment: Your first and third sub-clauses are the same! I have taken the liberty of making an arbitrary change to the third one; if you don't like this, or you have a better way of changing it, you may do so with the 'edit' button below your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deleting *to* in your second and third sub-clauses is permissible (but not required)<sup>†</sup>.

I suggest that you should be guided in your choice of including or deleting the *to* by the complexity of your sub-clauses. In this case, the sub-clauses are fairly short, so it’s easy for the reader to keep the commanding verb *help* in mind from one sub-clause to the next; you can readily drop the *to*. When the clauses are heavier or more complex, the *to* should be retained, to remind the reader of the construction:

> The methods helps to improve the quality of the software (often quite substantially), to shorten the time to market (in our experience, by several weeks), and to lower production costs (by a factor of 15%-20%).

---

<sup>†</sup> In fact, it can be deleted in the first phrase as well, since *help* may be used with both a bare infinitive and a marked infinitive.

> The method helps improve the quality of the software.

Note that this is true specifically with *help* - some other verbs require one or the other. *Want*, for instance, requires the marked infinitive: *I want **to** improve the quality of the software.)

Comment: Why, in your example, do you use a comma before "and to lower production costs" but no comma before "to shorten the time"? Is this intended?

Comment: @hplieninger No, it's a mistake: you have sharp eyes! I'll fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Both lines are grammatically correct. I prefer the first. As a matter of fact, you can delete the first "to" in the first line. As a *very* general rule, particularly when writing things of a technical nature, the fewer words it takes to get a point across, the better.

You've repeated the phrase "improve the quality of software", I assume that was in error or just a filler to emphasize the question? EDIT: StoneyB fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

This question already has good answers, but I thought I'd type up another way to think about it.

---

### Sentence one

Let's pretend you're starting with these three sentences:

> ​1. The method helps to improve the quality of the software.
>   ​2. The method helps to shorten the time to market.
>   ​3. The method helps to lower production costs.

We'll join them with *and*:

> ​the method helps to improve the quality of the software,
>   ​the method helps to shorten the time to market, 　　　　　*and*
>   ​the method helps to lower production costs.

But we're repeating more things that we need to.

We can get rid of *the method*:

> ​the method helps to improve the quality of the software,
>   <s>the method</s> helps to shorten the time to market, 　　　　　*and*
>   ​<s>the method</s> helps to lower production costs.

We can get rid of *the method helps*:

> ​the method helps to improve the quality of the software,
>   <s>the method helps</s> to shorten the time to market, 　　　　　*and*
>   ​<s>the method helps</s> to lower production costs.

Or we can get rid of *the method helps to*:

> ​the method helps to improve the quality of the software,
>   <s>the method helps to</s> shorten the time to market, 　　　　　*and*
>   ​<s>the method helps to</s> lower production costs.

---

### Sentence two

As the other answers say, you can even get rid of the first *to*.  Why?  Because *help* is one of the few verbs that takes either a *to*-infinitival or bare infinitival complement.  In other words, you can either *help to do something* or *help do something*.

But if we get rid of *to* in your example, we're starting with a different set of sentences:

> ​1. The method helps improve the quality of the software.
>   ​2. The method helps shorten the time to market.
>   ​3. The method helps lower production costs.

Let's join them with *and* again:

> ​the method helps improve the quality of the software,
>   ​the method helps shorten the time to market, 　　　　　*and*
>   ​the method helps lower production costs.

Now let's get rid of *the method*:

> ​the method helps improve the quality of the software,
>   <s>​the method</s> helps shorten the time to market, 　　　　　*and*
>   <s>​the method</s> helps lower production costs.

We can get rid of *helps*, too:

> ​the method helps improve the quality of the software,
>   <s>​the method helps</s> shorten the time to market, 　　　　　*and*
>   <s>​the method helps</s> lower production costs.

And now we're done!  We have the shorter sentence that Jolenealaska recommends.

Comment: Note: You should capitalize the first letter of each sentence.  I didn't in my examples because I wanted the phrases to line up vertically :-)